# Linux: Number of characters in a text file on lines 'x' through 'y'

Tags: linux, unix

How do I print the number of characters on lines x - y of a text file?

I tried using `wc -m filename.txt`
but I couldn't figure out how to limit the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sed` command to select the lines you want and then pipe the output into `wc`. Something like this would select lines 6-10 and print the number of characters:

`sed -n '6,10p' filename.txt | wc -m`

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
head -y filename | tail -(y-x+1) | wc -m
```

Comment: This gives the wrong answer. For example, `y==10`, `x==1` will print only  the tenth line, rathter than the intended first ten lines.

Comment: The `tail -x` dictates how many lines will be returned from the original file to consider.

Edit: You'd have to use the number of total lines you wanted to check instead. (Had an off by one error there, sorry)

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk '{ print NR, "-", length($0)}' filename.txt
```

It will print the line number `NR` and the characters per line `length($0)` of `filename.txt` so output will be something like:

```
1 - 3 # line 1 with 3 characters
2 - 0 # line 2 with no characters
...
```

In case you just want to print the number of characters for a specific range, let's say from line 1 to 3, this could be used:

```
awk 'NR>=1 && NR<=3 { print length($0)}' filename.txt
```